# In Recycleview , Why current row keeping previous Model class name, even after refreshing row ? See code

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I have a `RecyclerView`, In it i have some rows showing `(Text View 1) Product name` , `Button` and a `Text View 2` ,
This `Text View 2` is just to test the problem, When i press `Button` in several `rows` to add it works fine But the issue is when i press remove after remove in several rows, Its updating `Text View 2` with previous row's `Product Name`, So i don't know why its keeping previous rows name saved somewhere while i refreshed the row by `notifyItemChanged(position)`. Here is a test version of my `Project` showing the issue, Can anyone exactly say why its happening and how to solve it,
Run the project to see whats happening exactly.
This is my `RecyclerView`.

```
public class Recyclerview extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recyclerview.MyViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Product> list;

    public Recyclerview(Context context, ArrayList<Product> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_product, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = list.get(position);

        holder.xName.setText(product.getName());

        SharedPreferences sPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Item details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sPrefs.contains(product.getName())) {
            holder.test.setText(product.getName());

            holder.addButton.setText("Remove");
        } else {
            holder.addButton.setText("Add");
        }
        holder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (holder.addButton.getText().toString().equals("Add")) {

                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("Item Name", product.getName());
                    saveMap(product.getName(), hashMap);

                    notifyItemChanged(holder.getLayoutPosition());

                } else if (holder.addButton.getText().toString().equals("Remove")) {

                    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Item details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit()
                            .remove(product.getName());
                    prefsEditor.apply();

                    notifyItemChanged(holder.getLayoutPosition());
                }
            }

            private void saveMap(String key, Object obj) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Item details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(obj);
                editor.putString(key, json);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Button addButton;
        TextView xName, test;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            xName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            addButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
            test = itemView.findViewById(R.id.testUid);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Model class`

```
public class Product {

    Context mContext;
    String name;

    public Product(Context mContext, String name) {

        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public Context getmContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setmContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is my `Main Activity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recview;
    Recyclerview productAdapter;
    ArrayList<Product> productList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recview, false);
        recview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        productList.add(new Product(this,"Sugar"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Coffee"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Tea"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Milk"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Vegetable"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Bread"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Jam"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Butter"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Sandwich"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Roll"));
        productList.add(new Product(this,"Salt"));
        productAdapter = new Recyclerview(this, productList);
        recview.setAdapter(productAdapter);
    }
}
```

This is `activity_main.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#9C9696"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_product"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my `row_product.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Nothing"
            android:id="@+id/testUid"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#A10000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/testUid"
            app:layout_wrapBehaviorInParent="horizontal_only" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/testUid" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you MUST set every `View` in `onBindViewHolder` and you are not doing this in below snippet

```
    if (sPrefs.contains(product.getName())) {
        holder.test.setText(product.getName());

        holder.addButton.setText("Remove");
    } else {
        holder.addButton.setText("Add");
    }
```

`holder.test` don't have any text set in `else`, so it will stay same as previously set if this is recycled item. you should probably clean this line then

```
    } else {
        holder.test.setText("");
        holder.addButton.setText("Add");
    }
```

get familiar with **"recycling pattern"**, how it works any why... [HERE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/view-recycling-in-android-with-listview/) you have an example for old-fashioned `ListView`. not every developer was using recycling pattern in adapter, but it's crucial for performance, thus for this reason (and probably some other) Google decided to make new widget called `RecyclerView`, which has recycling pattern "built-in", even got name from it

PS. don't keep `Context` in model, never

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother, I just added payload in notifyItemChanged(holder.getLayoutPosition() , ""); and the problem is gone, i still dont know How,

Comment: [`notifyItemChanged(int position)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int)) and [`notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)) shouldn't make any difference, as you are not using this `payload` object. imo crucial in here is `holder.test.setText("");` in `else` and nothing more needed to do

Comment: If i m not changing `test` in `else` its remaining as the current row name after using`payload Object`

Comment: sadly I don't see relationship... passing `""` as payload will cause `onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position, @NonNull List<Object> payloads)` call. you aren't overriding it, so by default it is calling `onBindViewHolder(holder, position);` dropping whole `payloads` object. if doubt that your method call exchange is fixing anything, please ensure, make more tests, longer list etc...